# Count value Pandas and combining with other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have the following dataframes.:

```
ServiceHierarchy

id    ClientConnectionID
SH1    CN01
SH2    CN02
SH3    CN03
```

ServicePath

```
id 
SH1
SH1
SH1
SH2
SH2
SH3
SH4
```

I want to calculate `count_value()` of each id of ServiceHierarchy in which can be found in ServicePath dataframe  and return the list in ServiceHierarchy with the corresponds count of the value.
The result would be the following:

```
id    ClientConnectionID    count
SH1    CN01                   2
SH2    CN02                   6
SH3    CN03                   3
```

I started by `data_ServicePath['Id'].value_counts()` where it returns only the count values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are close, need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
ServiceHierarchy['count'] = ServiceHierarchy['id'].map(data_ServicePath['id'].value_counts())
print (ServiceHierarchy)
    id ClientConnectionID  count
0  SH1               CN01      3
1  SH2               CN02      2
2  SH3               CN03      1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (data_ServicePath['id'].value_counts())
SH1    3
SH2    2
SH3    1
SH4    1
Name: id, dtype: int64
```